# Docpad - pull data from JSON file

Tags: json, coffeescript, docpad

This is my piece of code

```
<% for file in @getCollection("tumblrs").toJSON(): %>
<li>
<a href="<%= file.url %>"><%= file['title'] %></a>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Here is my dataset

```
{
"blog_name": "weface",
"id": 861340745,
"slug": "ssssaaawweeet",
"type": "text",
"date": "2010-07-26 13:28:07 GMT",
"timestamp": 1280150887,
"state": "published",
"format": "html",
"tags": [],
"highlighted": [],
"note_count": 0,
"title": "Ssssaaawweeet!",
}
```

How would I go about getting 'title'?

Comment: You can find out the above by doing: `<pre><%= JSON.stringify(file) %></pre>` inside your for loop

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I put the <pre> script into my loop and it returned a string of data. I can see the the data I want is in the "source" tag. `<a href="<%= file.url %>"><%= file.source %></a>` returns the json data I want but I'm not sure how I would go about getting a tag such as "blog_name" `<a href="<%= file.url %>"><%= file.source.blog_name %></a>` doesn't work. Is there a way of getting this data?